# Using json data after loading it using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, openlayers

So I'm trying to load in a json file that has header and data attributes using Javascript, and then am trying to use the data for in other methods. The json file is loading just fine (evidenced by the "console.log(header.dx)" ), but the code isn't updating my outer array (as evidenced by the call to "console.log(productPoints.length, productPoints)" ). What am I doing wrong?

```
var productFile = "aJsonFile.json";
var productPoints = [];
$.getJSON(productFile)
  .done(function(json) {
    var data = json[0].data;
    var header = json[0].header;
    console.log(header.dx);
    k = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < header.ny; j++) {
      for (var i = 0; i < header.nx; i++, k++) {
        var point = new ol.geom.Point(
          [floorMod(180 + header.lo1 + i * header.dx, 360) - 180, 
          header.la1 - j * header.dy]
        );
        var feature = new ol.Feature({ geometry: point, value: data[k] });
        productPoints.push(feature);
      } 
    }
  });
console.log(productPoints.length, productPoints);

var floorMod = function(a, n) {
  var f = a - n * Math.floor(a / n);
  return f === n ? 0 : f;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax calls are asynchronous. The ajax call may end after you log the array. Try moving your console.log inside *done()* function.

```
var productFile = "aJsonFile.json";
var productPoints = [];
$.getJSON(productFile)
  .done(function(json) {
    var data = json[0].data;
    var header = json[0].header;
    console.log(header.dx);
    k = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < header.ny; j++) {
      for (var i = 0; i < header.nx; i++, k++) {
        var point = new ol.geom.Point(
          [floorMod(180 + header.lo1 + i * header.dx, 360) - 180, 
          header.la1 - j * header.dy]
        );
        var feature = new ol.Feature({ geometry: point, value: data[k] });
        productPoints.push(feature);
      } 
    }
    console.log(productPoints.length, productPoints);
  });


var floorMod = function(a, n) {
  var f = a - n * Math.floor(a / n);
  return f === n ? 0 : f;
};
```

Comment: Dang, why do I keep forgetting about that? Shame on me.